# SQL sum and divide

Tags: sql

Basically I'm trying to workout how many error's there would be per million, I'm not sure this is right

```
 (sum(countAudit) * sum(error)) / 1000000
```

This was another idea I had,

```
(sum(countAudit * 100) + sum(error * 100)) / 1000000
```

Not sure if I'm on the right track

Comment: `(sum(error) / sum(countAudit)) * 1000000`

Comment: What Data Types are `countAudit` and `error` ?

Comment: Just basic numbers, Bacon Bits gave me the answer, seems to work